# avoid that tkcalendar dateentry widget put date by default. I need to save date of cancelation without date sometimes

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to have a `tkcalendar` dateentry that has to should be empty until I put or choose a date. But this widget is configured to fix a not valid date at the focusout and consider an empty date an invalid date putting the today date. I am expecting that letf no date if I don't put or choose one. Here a test I did

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from tkinter import messagebox

def date_validation (event):
    fecha=date_entry.get_date()
    try:
        datetime.strftime(fecha, "%d/%m/%Y")
        return True
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showwarning("Date Error", "Date not valid")
        return False

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Date test")

date_entry = DateEntry(window, selectmode="day")
date_entry.pack()
date_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
date_entry.configure(validate='none')
date_entry.bind("<FocusOut>", date_validation)

field_entry = ttk.Entry(window)
field_entry.pack(pady=20)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)